# Using ngIf and ngFor in option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

I want to use ngIf and ngFor in one line. I know it is not possible but is there any other method to do this?

Here is my code:

```
<option *ngIf="tmpLanguage.id!=languages.id" 
        *ngFor="let tmpLanguage of languages" [ngValue]="tmpLanguage.id">
     {{tmpLanguage.identificatie}}
</option>
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Only one structural directive is allowed on one element at a time.

As a workaround you can use `<ng-container>` which is not stamped to the DOM

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let tmpLanguage of languages">
  <option *ngIf="tmpLanguage.id!=languages.id"  [ngValue]="tmpLanguage.id" >{{tmpLanguage.identificatie}}</option>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let tmpLanguage of languages">
  <option *ngIf="tmpLanguage.id!=languages.id" [ngValue]="tmpLanguage.id" >
    {{tmpLanguage.identificatie}}
  </option>
</ng-container>
```