# Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. ngFor and ngIf together

Tags: angular, ngfor

I'm trying to get the li element to display 
{{info.email}} USER ON THIS DEVICE only if localStorage variable matches.I need it inside the li element as this data is coming from the database. Can anyone shed some light on how to achieve this ?

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let info of infos" (click)="personTapped($event, info);" *ngIf="(window.localStorage.getItem('userLoggedIn') === info.email)"> {{info.username}} (USER ON THIS DEVICE) 
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why don't you expose the list of things you actually want to display from the component instance? `*ngFor="let info of infosToShow()"`.

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40860933/ngif-and-ngfor-on-td-td-element http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39570915/using-ngif-and-ngfor-in-option http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657821/ngif-and-ngfor-on-same-element-causing-error

Answer (score 0):

As yurzui said, you can do it like this: [*ngIf and *ngFor on <td></td> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40860933/ngif-and-ngfor-on-td-td-element) using the `ng-container`.

or use `[hidden]` instead of `*ngIf`.