# Excluding a value from ngFor

Tags: angular2-directives, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I have a dropdown that is populated with an `*ngFor` that iterates over a list of users. I want to exclude the current user from the list. Creating a whole pipe seems overkill. Is there a simple way to do this since Angular2 won't let me have both an `*ngFor` and an `*ngIf` on the same element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *ngFor for the parent div and then for the child div use *ngIf to check whether it is a current user.

```
`<div *ngFor=“ let user of users”><div *ngIF= “user != currentUser”>user</div></div>`
```

Comment: This is very similar to what I finally found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39570915/using-ngif-and-ngfor-in-option Thanks!