# How to put ng for and ng if in <options> angular 6?

Tags: html, angular6

I need to use ngIf and ngFor on the

```
<option *ngFor="let price of product['pricingDetails']" *ngIf="price['chainPrice']" >
```

but it shows me `Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute prefixed with *` error. What is the best way to use both in the  element?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using ngIf and ngFor in option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39570915/using-ngif-and-ngfor-in-option)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\*ngIf and \*ngFor on same element causing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657821/ngif-and-ngfor-on-same-element-causing-error)

Comment: Sasuke Uchiha thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try using this ,

```
<select>

<ng-container *ngFor="let price of product['pricingDetails']">
<option  *ngIf="price['chainPrice']" >
   {{ display anythjing }}
</option>

</ng-container>
</select>
```

Try my updated code .

Comment: What I'm asking is I need *ngIf for the options only. The above method will produce empty options element

Comment: This will still create an option. That just won't have anything in it but still the option will be created. That not required i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
[hidden]="!price['chainPrice']"
```

instead of this:

```
*ngIf="price['chainPrice']"
```